# Hexadecimal string value to 0x Byte

Tags: java, hex, byte

How do I convert string value of a hexadecimal to be used as a byte. For example, I get the hexadecimal string value through -

```
 String strVal = String.format("%02x", buf[i]); //lets say it is "3D"
```

Now I want to convert that into a byte, so I can do something like this

```
byte bVal =  0x[value?] //0x3D;
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into commons-codec?  That'll take care of it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
String hex = ...;
int temp = Integer.parseInt(hex , 16);

byte result = (byte) temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getBytes().So strVal.getBytes().